# How to open two page in one submit in html?

Tags: html, css, forms

Hei, i want to ask about html. How to open 2 page in one click on form action ?
I just try with two action but never work, here i use to make form:

```
<form action = "http://www.google.com" method = "get" target = "_blank">
```

That is i use to open google when submit, but how to open 2 site or page in one submit ?

i try like this not work

```
<form action = "https://www.google.com" action="https://www.facebook.com" method = "get" target = "_blank">
```

Im sorry im just newbie but please help me to find out.

Thank you very much

Comment: Use code section to show your HTML, looks like your HTML is stripped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form add a `action property` where you have to provide the link to one of your `HTML` page.

Then to submit button add a `onclick property` and provide the link to another page to be opened in a new window.

```
form action="/link/of/your/first/html/page"<br/>
 <!--content--> 
input type="submit" onclick="window.open('/link/of/second/html/page','other_window')
```

Hope it was help full.

Comment: I have fix it with your code with little modifed. Thank you very much

Comment: Can i ask you how to make hidden password ? i use Password :<br>
 <input type = "text" name = "pass" placeholder="Password"
      "size" = "8"> but the password is not hidden, like that(*****), how to make it hidden(*****) ? Thanks

Comment: give input type = "password"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a id="test" href="#"> CLick </a>
<script type="text/javascript">

  document.getElementById("test").onclick = function(){
   window.open("http://www.google.com",'_blank');
   window.open("http://www.p3php.in",'_blank');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Im sorry, i just check open with no internet connection not work but when im open with internet connection its work, why ?

Comment: Can i ask you how to make hidden password ? i use Password :<br>
 <input type = "text" name = "pass" placeholder="Password"
      "size" = "8"> but the password is not hidden, like that(*****), how to make it hidden(*****) ? Thanks

Comment: I don't know with js why it's only showing on server side, but form gets and puts call to a php file.  PHP is only processed on the server side.  So it has to be uploaded to the internet where the php processor is on your site host's servers.

Comment: The password question is completely new.  I'd search and see if it's been asnwered before and if not, post it as a new question.

Comment: Ok thank you. So if we use js with have to on internet connections ?

Comment: If your pointing your anchor tags to an external link..you should need internet

Answer (score 0):

By changing the input type to password 
eg::

```html
<input type = "password" name = "pass" placeholder="Password" size = "8">
```

you make password field hidden